# Requisição DELETE Ajax em um controlador SDN Floodlight

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sdn

Tenho uma função no meu JavaScript que faz uma requisição Ajax para a interface REST de um controlador Floodlight.

```
function excluir(nome)
{
    var jsonExclui = ("{" + '"name": "'+nome+'" }');
    alert(jsonExclui);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://192.168.56.99:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json",
        method: "DELETE",
        //  type: 'DELETE',
        data: jsonExclui,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.status);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert("Deu erro : "+data.status);
        }
    });
}
```

O método DELETE é aceito e consta na documentação do controlador SDN.

[Documentção1](https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1343518)

[Documentção2](https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/display/floodlightcontroller/Floodlight+REST+API)

Mas ao analisar o console do navegador percebi que ele me diz que estou enviando OPTIONS e não DELETE.

> Accept-Ranges:bytes Allow:DELETE, POST Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Type:application/json Date:Thu, 14 May 2015 11:46:43 GMT
>   Server:Restlet-Framework/2.3.1 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>   Remote Address:192.168.56.99:8085 Request
>   URL:http://192.168.56.99:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json Request
>   Method:OPTIONS Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Isso é comum?

Comment: Os pedidos standard de AJAX são `GET, HEAD or POST`. Todos os outros fazem o browser fazer uma chamada de confimação antes de enviar o pedido real. Essa chamada de confirmação tem método `OPTIONS`, isto é normal e a resposta do servidor ao "preflight" (essa chamada de confirmação) deve ser `200`.

Depois dessa chamada "preflight" ser aceite o AJAX envia o pedido real. Na resposta que tens diz `Code: 405 Method Not Allowed`, tens a certeza que esse método é aceite? Tens o link da documentação?

Comment: Quando faço a requisição o navegador me diz que para aquela url (http://192.168.56.99:8085/wm/staticflowpusher/json)                                    são permitidos os métodos POST e DELETE, o OPTIONS não. Documentação:(https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1343518)                                                                                               (https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/display/floodlightcontroller/Floodlight+REST+API)

Answer (score 1):

Pode estar faltando o `switch`, assim:

```
curl -X DELETE -d'{"name":"myflow1", "switch":"00:00:04:f0:21:11:3d:78"}' http://192.168.0.220:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
```

Comment: Usando curl não é preciso mandar o switch no JSON. ' DELETE -d'{"name":"flow-mod-1"}' http://10.93.15.187:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json '  só enviando o nome ele já me retorna como deletado: '{"status" : "Entry flow-mod-1 deleted"}'. Na documentação não consta a necessidade de mandar o Switch no JSON. Creio que o problema seja o navegador que faz essa chamada de confirmação, como o Sergio citou, e a url não aceita essa chamada OPTIONS, por isso da este erro. Se houvesse uma forma de burlar essa pré-chamada...